# How to index a csv file

Tags: solr

How to index a csv/excel sheet in solr? For example, I have data like below in a csv file

```
row1
row2
row3
row4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the exampledocs folder that comes with solr also contains a books.csv file . The first row should contain the field names, while the rest of them will contain the field values. . Try indexing it with the post.sh script.